# I tried creating VM from Snapshot which is taken by cross subscription migration, deployment getting failed while VM creation

Tags: azure

I took snapshot of OS-Disk and migrated it to other subscription. Created a Disk out of Snapshot, Tried creating VM out of the new disk using portal.

Deployment got failed with following error. Initial VM was created by Azure marketplace image. I am not understanding whats wrong here. Help me to understand whats wrong here.

**Error:**
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"VMMarketplaceInvalidInput\",\r\n \"message\": \"Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image requires Plan information in the request. VM: '/subscriptions/1bf608d4-1499-4732-8948-2c629b705e8d/resourceGroups/ai-ds-vm/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/eureka-ds-dev-a'.\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

Best Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 0):

Error indicate that you create it VM initially with a Markeplace email that has a **Plan**.

[image]

If SKU plan still exist you will need to use it to recreate VM, if it no longer exist you will not be able to recreate VM. Below is a link to another forum that goes through the recreation options.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733411/how-to-fix-azure-portal-not-deploying-a-vm-from-image-due-to-no-plan-error